# "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail" doesn't generate mail views

Tags: php, laravel, email

I tried to customize the component of mail on Laravel 5.8. At first I tried to copy mail directory from `Illuminate/Mail` to `resources/views` using command

> php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail

but it didn't create anything, although it generated the success message

> Copied Directory [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views] To [/resources/views/vendor/mail]
>   Publishing complete.

Why did it happens? I don't have any clue.

Comment: Did you check folder "/resources/views/vendor" ?

Comment: Check folder permissions.

Comment: well, I think it was the problem from my editor, it was not automatically refreshed. Prolem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You may see some success instead running

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Then selecting the laravel mail tag from the list of options provided (12)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).